how to solve ModuleNotFoundError error in django code
I am developing a webtool using django. I have already installed and activated the virtual environment. I am getting the following error which seems to be very easy to fix:
    from .views import (
  File "/home/example/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from subscriptions.models import Subscription
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subscriptions'

and tried to install the package using the following command:
pip install subscription

and imported using the following command:
from subscriptions.models import Subscription

but still getting the same error. how can I fix the issue?

did you mean pip install subscriptions instead of pip install subscription? https://pypi.org/project/subscriptions/

Actually there is no module named subscriptions from the project source here. [github.com]
Instead the line to import correctly should be:
from subscription.models import Subscription
